# Call WCF service remotely

Tags: wcf, service

I have a WCF service that is hosted in IIS and remote database in a location.

I have a client that is working in B location. Each location is away from each other.

The remote database doesn't accept 1433 sql port for remote requests.

I added a WCF service to my web app:

```
//// WCF Method ////
public SqlDataReader DataReader(string query)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(RemoteConnection());
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);     

    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}

public  string RemoteConnection()
{
    var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=sa;Password=abc123abc;");   
    return con.ConnectionString;
}
```

I am calling the WCF from remote side like below

```
     WcfWebService srv = new WcfWebService();
     GridView1.DataSource = srv.DataReader("SELECT * FROM TABLE);
```

but I get an error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

I just want to query remote database via WCF service from remote side. Which methods do I have in this case?

Comment: You can not return a SqlDataReader from WCF. You can return a DataTable though.

Comment: normally I have 2 methods one of that return datatable the other is return dataset , But I want to query remote database via wcf in windows app.

Comment: Your WCF code (posted) that calls SQL Server is fine. That error should be on the client side which  make sense because WCF runtime is unable to serialise 'SqlDataReader' object. Even if it was able to serialise it, the client can not remotely retrieve the data from 'SQLDataReader' object. For each dataset/table from database you need separate method on service that will be responsible to call the database and return that dataset/table back to client. I hope it makes sense!

Comment: so you mean ,WCF only return dataset or datatabe to client side remotely .

Comment: @bybirol You can return a DataTable or DataSet, but they will not be connected to a database. You should looked into WCF Data Services which uses the Open Data Protocol (OData) to expose and consume data.

Comment: May u give me a example .